# Table-like image grid in CSS (but with a twist)

Tags: css, grid, center, centering

I want to create a table-like image grid. Each thumbnail image (size and orientation vary) is meant to sit centered in it's own DIV. Each row should contain four images, after that I want an automatic "line break" to happen, caused by the size of the enclosing TD, with the result looking like this:

XXXX
XXXX
XX

The code below works as intended in Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome. But in Internet Explorer 7/8/9 I run into two problems:

1) Images are not vertically centered, they sit at the top of the DIV.
2) The "line break" does not happen. The row of images disappears out of sight to the right...

CSS:

```
.outer-div {display: inline; float:left; clear:right;}

.inner-div 
{
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-div"><div class="inner-div">img.jpg</div></div>
```

Comment: I can't recreate the effects you describe with your code. Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to the `.inner-div` CSS:

```
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
```

I think what's happening is IE doesn't recognize the `display:table-cell`, so you need to use a hack (or some other method of telling only IE to use `display:inline` with `zoom:1`).